# failover-abort-no-good-slave master mymaster

Tags: redis, sentinel

I'm trying to set up a highly available and fault tolerance Redis,
but in this scenario, all sentinel stuck and can't select a new master
I set `down-after-milliseconds 1000` and `failover-timeout 2000`
when all sentinel goes down and then my master goes down when sentinels go up cant select the new master, and show log `-failover-abort-no-good-slave master mymaster`.
I know this issue happened because of this part of the code(sentinel.c)
`if (slave->master_link_down_time > max_master_down_time) continue;`
i there any parameter to config sentinel always select a master in failover and don't -failover-abort-no-good-slave master mymaster?

Comment: Were you able to find answer for this question?